# Java Util Logging redirection to Log4j2 not working for Spring Boot applications

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to redirect all logging frameworks to Log4j2 in my Spring Boot application. It works fine for Java Commons Logging, SLF4J, and Log4j 1.x.
Unfortunately the Java Util Logging (JUL) redirection does not work because `java.util.logging.Logger` is used by the Plexus Launcher at a time when the application classpath has not been fully assembled.

The Log4j2 documentation demands to set the VM parameter `-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.LogManager` or to call the `System.setProperty("java.util.logging.manager", "org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.LogManager")` method to make the redirection work. Neither of them work:

- `System.setProperty()` in my application code comes far too late. Some startup code already did some calls to `LogManager` or `Logger` so that the Redirection-LogManager cann be installed anymore.
- The VM parameter also does not work as the application classpath is not available at the point in time when the

The call to `System.setProperty()` gets ignored because the Java Util Logging framework is already initialized. With the VM parameter the following exception occurs:

```
$ mvn spring-boot:run -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.LogManager

Could not load Logmanager "org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.LogManager"
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.LogManager
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$1.run(LogManager.java:195)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$1.run(LogManager.java:181)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:181)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.demandLogger(Logger.java:448)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:502)
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.Stopwatch.<clinit>(Stopwatch.java:27)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.<init>(InternalInjectorCreator.java:61)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:96)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:73)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.addPlexusInjector(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:481)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.<init>(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:206)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.container(MavenCli.java:542)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:279)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
```

Digging into the code shows that the initialization is caused by the Guice library, which uses JUL internally. In this case it is just a call to `com.google.inject.internal.util.Stopwatch.<clinit>(Stopwatch.java:27)`.

So the question is, does somone have an idea on how to resolve this?

**Update 2015-08-23:**
The suggestion from below to add the configuration property `<fork>true</fork>` works for running the application via the Spring boot Maven plugin `mvn spring-boot:run`.

Unfortunately it does not work when running the application via the command line `java -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.LogManager -jar myapp.jar`. In this case the following exception occurs:

```
Could not load Logmanager "org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.LogManager"
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.LogManager
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$1.run(LogManager.java:195)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$1.run(LogManager.java:181)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:181)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.demandLogger(Logger.java:448)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:502)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:43)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.ExecutableArchiveLauncher.<init>(ExecutableArchiveLauncher.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.ExecutableArchiveLauncher.<init>(ExecutableArchiveLauncher.java:45)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.<init>(JarLauncher.java:30)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:45)
```

So, unfortunately the Spring Boot Launcher is also using Java Util Logging and by that preventing JUL redirection with Log4j2.

I looked at the source-code of the class `org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher` and its child classes. The issue is caused by the declaration of the static logger variable in the `Launcher` class. This logger seems not to be used by any of the Launcher classes so it could easily be removed.
The question is whether the dependency to JUL could be removed completely to fix the JUL redirection issue? Maybe by using stderr for Launcher diagnostics, instead of JUL?

Answer (score 3):

Your current approach means that both Maven and your application will try to use the custom log manager. Maven attempting to use it is causing the exception that you are seeing.

You could configure Spring Boot's Maven plugin in your pom.xml to fork a separate JVM for your application:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <fork>true</fork>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

And then use `System.setProperty` in your application's main method. Forking a separate JVM will prevent Maven's own logging from messing things up before your configuration takes effect.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. This solves the issue for running the application via `mvn spring-boot:run` but unfortunately the flag `-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.LogManager` does not work when the application is started with `java -jar myapp.jar`.

Comment: If you set the system property in your application's main method, I'd hope that's early enough when using an executable jar file. If you need to specify it on the command line, make sure you provide the system property before `-jar my app.jar`. For example: `java -Djava.util.logging.manager=… -jar myapp.jar`

Comment: Unfortunately not, see my update above. I'm currently preparing a pull request to drop the Spring Boot Launcher dependency to Java Util Logging...

Comment: A pull request would be most welcome. I've opened an issue so that we (the Spring Boot team) don't forget about this: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/3815.

Comment: I explained the issue in detail on the ticket you just opened.